# Java code for creating Pentaho reports and this reports accept input as data integration(.ktr) file

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

I am looking for java code in which have to display Pentaho reports in HTML/PDF format with Data Integration(.ktr file) as input to the Pentaho reports.

Comment: Do you mean, like custom launcher? Or u want to embed report capabilities into your application?

Answer (score 0):

First of all most probably there is official documentation to API, chapter "**[Embedding the Reporting Engine Into a Java Application](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Freporting_embedders_guide%2Ftopic_embedding_engine.html)**"

Code it pretty simple

Create report using visual tool, assign data source as .ktr file, and code as example in tutorial.

Only u might need to customize path to *.ktr file which either can be made via official API (most probably) or prepare report *.prpt before to start report.

Pentaho Report Designer generate files with prpt extension which is just a zip file with a lot of xml files inside. So u need to unpack it (java.util.zip) and inside in folder **datasources** file kettle-ds.xml. Use any suitable xml parser to change path to *.ktr file and pack it back. Then pass customized report to report engine.