# Integrating the Pentaho with source as PDI to Java

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

Tried out to run the PRPT  from JAVA code. Its worked fine with the Parameter as well.

While am trying to run the PRPT with the source as PDI, Am getting the Parse Error.

Version of the software: Pentaho 8.1 Community Edition

[Java code for creating Pentaho reports and this reports accept input as data integration(.ktr) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474437/java-code-for-creating-pentaho-reports-and-this-reports-accept-input-as-data-int)

Refereed the above link but i could not able to understand it.

Kindly suggest me how to define the Ktr path in the PRPT dataset (PFA screenshot).

[PDI Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smG1b.png)

Is there any other API need to include to run the KTR in the PRPT file. Please make this is a Priority and helped out me, Please share if you have reference link or documentation related to that.

[PDI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7boTC.png)

Comment: It's the the full path your PDI transformation from where you want to get the data. You have a browse button to do it. Do you have a PDI running and producing the data you want to make your report on ?

Comment: By the way, are you new to the PDI ?

Comment: With the vague details you provide, I just assume you are not importing all the necessary libraries to get it working. Seems like the same problem I had time ago with charting.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with pentaho(carte) pass params and get value as webservices
[Pentaho carte](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+Configuration)
pan.sh -option=value arg1 arg2

in .ktr file use text file output and checked pass output to servlet

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ali Dadmand. I could not to relate your answer to my clarification.could you please elaborate it. How to give the PDI path in PRPT file while calling the prpt from java code. currently am giving the path like D:/Foldername/Transofrmationname.ktr, Its working fine in local. how do I define this path while am calling via Java API.  While am unizip the prpt file i got datasource\kettle-ds file . In that the path mentioned like D:/Foldername/Transofrmationname.ktr.

Comment: <data:kettle-datasource xmlns:data="http://jfreereport.sourceforge.net/namespaces/datasources/kettle"><data:query-file name="Query 1" repository="" filename="D:\Folder1\T_transformation.ktr" step="Output_Value" stop-on-error="true"><data:variable variable-name="Param_Sort_Test_Protocol_Name" formula="=[Param_Sort_Test_Protocol_Name]"/><data:variable variable-name="Param_Sort_Test_Profile_name" formula="=[Param_Sort_Test_Profile_name]"/><data:variable variable-name="Param_Sort_Created_Date" formula="=[Param_Sort_Created_Date]"/>

Comment: use variable path : ${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}

Comment: I have done the same thing. But its showing unable to load the kettle transformation.Is there any other approach to fix it.  Please refer the image description - PDI Error

Comment: Any Suggestion on it. got the error like "Unable to parse the document: ResourceKey{schema=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.bundleloader.ZipResourceBundleLoader, identifier=content.xml, factoryParameters={org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.FactoryParameterKey{name=repository-loader}=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.docbundle.bundleloader.ZipResourceBundleLoader@39179e52, org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.FactoryParameterKey{name=repository}=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.repository.zipreader.ZipReadRepository@3533bb9e},

Comment: parent=ResourceKey{schema=org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.loader.URLResourceLoader"

Comment: Its worked. Without giving anypath. Just mentioned the transformation name alone. eg: T_Check_one.ktr . Thanks Dadmand.